# Word + C# дописать в файл

Tags: c#, ms-word

Здравствуйте! Есть шаблон повестки `*.dotx`, нужно написать программу, которая будет подставлять данные в этот шаблон и записывать их в `*.docx` документ. Т.е. нужно 5 повесток к примеру, программа считывает `*.dotx`, заменяет в определенных местах текст и заносит в `*.docx` файл (дописывает) результат и так циклом 5 раз, с новыми данными.

```
private DocX GetRejectionLetterTemplate()
    {

        // Adjust the path so suit your machine:
        string fileName = @"C:\DocXExample.docx";

        // Set up our paragraph contents:
        string headerText = "Rejection Letter";
        string letterBodyText = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        string paraTwo = ""
            + "Dear %APPLICANT%" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine
            + "I am writing to thank you for your resume. Unfortunately, your skills and "
            + "experience do not match our needs at the present time. We will keep your "
            + "resume in our circular file for future reference. Don't call us, "
            + "we'll call you. "

            + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine
            + "Sincerely, "
            + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine
            + "Jim Smith, Corporate Hiring Manager";

        // Title Formatting:
        var titleFormat = new Formatting();
        titleFormat.FontFamily = new System.Drawing.FontFamily("Arial Black");
        titleFormat.Size = 18D;
        titleFormat.Position = 12;

        // Body Formatting
        var paraFormat = new Formatting();
        paraFormat.FontFamily = new System.Drawing.FontFamily("Calibri");
        paraFormat.Size = 10D;
        titleFormat.Position = 12;

        // Create the document in memory:
        var doc = DocX.Create(fileName);

        // Insert each prargraph, with appropriate spacing and alignment:
        Paragraph title = doc.InsertParagraph(headerText, false, titleFormat);
        title.Alignment = Alignment.center;

        doc.InsertParagraph(Environment.NewLine);
        Paragraph letterBody = doc.InsertParagraph(letterBodyText, false, paraFormat);
        letterBody.Alignment = Alignment.both;

        doc.InsertParagraph(Environment.NewLine);
        doc.InsertParagraph(paraTwo, false, paraFormat);
        doc.InsertParagraph(GetDocTextContent(@"C:\Template.dotx"), false, titleFormat);

        return doc;
    }
```

Это то, что у меня есть. Нужно в переменную `paraTwo` занести текст из *Template.dotx*. Не могу разобраться как считывать из *.docx*-файла с помощью библиотеки `DocX`.

Считываю из файла так:

```
DocX template = DocX.Load(@"C:\Template.dotx");
string str = template.Text;
```

Но не знаю, как сохранить форматирование и стили, чтобы шаблон добавлялся в документ в точности такой, как он есть.

Comment: Тут возможны варианты. Вы хотите использовать ActiveX, doc, docx напрямую, rtf? Net 2.0 или 4.0 ? Какую библиотеку для работы с word используете?

Comment: @nick_n_a, .net 4.0, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

Comment: @АнтонБурак вопрос не полный, напишите конкретно, что не получается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пользоваться Office.Interop - категорически не советую.
Сам раньше занимался подобными задачами, достоинство Interop только в том, что на него легче перейти с VBA - логика генерации документа аналогична, можно почти без изменений переносить результат записи макроса MS Office. В остальном одни минусы, как в использовании, так и для безопасности и стабильности работы.
Также немаловажный фактор - Interop работает очень медленно и результат может отличаться на разных машинах.

Рекомендую пользоваться *автономными* средствами. Логика построения документа в них может быть совсем другая, но разобраться можно. Работать будет на всех машинах и выдавать одинаковый результат.
Например:
 1. [Open XML SDK 2.0 для Microsoft Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/bb448854.aspx).
 2. [DocX](https://docx.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Поясните почему не рекомендуете `Office.Interop`. С какими проблемами сталкивались?

Comment: @astronavigator хотя бы то, что хостинг это не позволит. Еще куча проблем, если на вашем компьютере была одна версия офиса, на клиенте другая. Бывало так, что после установки на клиенте обновлений возникали сбои в работе. Также, может быть так, что в работу `Interop` вмешается кто-то сторонний, можно даже сделать окно видимым и смотреть как генерится документ и соотв. вмешаться мышькой и клавиатурой. Все исходит от того, как работает `Interop`  - запускается экземпляр `Office`, окно которого не видно пользователю, а все команды кода фактически обрабатывает этот процесс.

Comment: есть примеры использования?

Comment: @АнтонБурак Обычно на сайте каждого проекта бывает и документация и примеры.

Comment: @Ildar, спасибо, буду пробовать, правда в документации DocX не нашел ничего про то как считать из файла информацию... а ссылка с MSDN на Open XML говорит что страница не найдена

Comment: @АнтонБурак Чтение из файла это основы `c#`, к тому же не относится к проекту. На страницах проекта DocX можно найти документацию по DocX, использование этой библиотеки предполагает уже знание основ языка. Ознакомьтесь для начала: [System.IO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/system.io(v=vs.110).aspx), [XmlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx). Ссылка на `Open XML SDK` работает, но даже если бы не работала, могли бы [погуглить](https://www.google.ru/search?q=Open+XML+SDK&oq=Open+XML+SDK&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @Ildar, основы c# я знаю, чтение из файла задача не трудная, но так то docx это не совсем простой файл

Comment: @АнтонБурак Пардон, вы имели ввиду чтение с документа `.docx`? Сейчас код показать не смогу. Открываете документ, находите нужный параграф и где-то в пропертях будет текстовое значение этого параграфа, можно считывать и устанавливать новое значение.

Comment: @Ildar, может вы когда сможете пример все же скинете, если это вас не затруднит.

Comment: @АнтонБурак Давайте следовать правилам форума (см. например [Что означает «закрыт» или «требует правки»?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions), [Как задать хороший вопрос?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [...вопрос не отвечает стандартам качества?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error)), что бы сообщество могло получить пользу. Отредактируйте вопрос, что у вас получается и где есть затруднения.

Comment: Прошу открыть тему, дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @АнтонБурак Первая часть вопроса не понятна, там же все очевидно, вы каждый раз в один и тот же файл все пишете:     
      
      string fileName = @"C:\DocXExample.docx"; 
      var doc =  DocX.Create(fileName);

Comment: @Ildar, так мне и нужно в один файл писать... мне нужно из одного файла читать, и записывать в другой. Но не перезаписывать файл, а дописывать в него. со всем почти разобрался кроме того, как считать с файла с сохранением форматирования. т.е. считать со всеми стилями, шрифтами и т.д. как есть

Comment: @АнтонБурак Переформулируйте тогда первую часть вопроса и отметьте тревогой (справа от "править").