# Возможно ли подружить vba макрос и c#

Tags: c#, vba

У меня имеется Sharepoint приложение по сохранению выбранных файлов на файл-сервере. Необходимо перед загрузкой файла обрабатывать `xlsx` файл VBA макросом. Так как приложение использует C#, есть два варианта и какой из них правильный:

1. Возможно ли запускать макрос в самом приложении перед сохранением файла? Если да, то как?
2. Может стоит переписать VBA макрос на C#? Но тогда какие стоит использовать библиотеки и пример, если можно?

Answer (score 3):

Если запускать макросы, то это только `Office.Interop`, чего категорически не советую.
При всем желании, вряд ли найдется хостинг, который позволит использовать interop, это не безопасно, не надежно и в принципе подход неграмотный.

Посмотрите аналогичный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/561129/1426

Рекомендую пользоваться автономными средствами, не требующих предустановленного Office.
В дополнение к Open XML, DocX могу порекомендовать коммерческие продукты Aspose.Words и другие аналоги: https://stackoverflow.com/q/435323/3189289